# Get timestamp of one month ago in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database in which one table rapidly grows very large (several million rows every month or so) so I'd like to periodically archive the contents of that table into a separate table.

I'm intending to use a cron job to execute a .sql file nightly to archive all rows that are older than one month into the other table.

I have the query working fine, but I need to know how to dynamically create a timestamp of one month prior.

The `time` column is stored in the format `2013-10-27 06:53:12` and I need to know what to use in an SQL query to build a timestamp of exactly one month prior. For example, if today is October 27, 2013, I want the query to match all rows where time < `2013-09-27 00:00:00`

Comment: "The time column is stored in the format 2013-10-27 06:53:12" - you should use a [`timestamp` column](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) for that, not a formatted string, as it will make things like this a lot easier and more efficient.

Comment: "30 days" is more precise than "one month", and "exactly one month" is essentially meaningless. In SQL, if you subtract exactly one month from 2013-03-28, 03-29, 03-30, and 03-31, and you get the same answer: 2013-02-28. Does that matter?

Comment: @IMSoP Unfortunately, I don't have control over the database structure. I'm running a Quassel IRC Core, and having 18 million rows in the backlog table results in the client loading very slowly, so I need to archive all but recent rows in order to maintain client stability.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Question was answered by a friend in IRC:

`'now'::timestamp - '1 month'::interval`

Having the timestamp return 00:00:00 wasn't terrible important, so this works for my intentions.

Comment: DateTime functions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: note that the "friendly" version of this is `CURRENT_DATE - cast('1 months' as interval)`

Answer (score 70):

```
select date_trunc('day', NOW() - interval '1 month')
```

This query will return date one month ago from now and round time to 00:00:00.

Comment: Note that this will return an actual timestamp; from the wording of the question, the actual column has a string, so you will need to cast it to compare: `WHERE CAST("time" as timestamp) < date_trunc('day', now() - interval '1 month')`

Answer (score 4):

When you need to query for the data of previous month, then you need to query for the respective date column having month values as (current_month-1).

```
SELECT * 
FROM {table_name}
WHERE {column_name} >= date_trunc('month', current_date-interval '1' month)
    AND {column_name} < date_trunc('month', current_date)
```

The first condition of where clause will search the date greater than the first day (00:00:00 Day 1 of Previous Month)of previous month and second clause will search for the date less than the first day of current month(00:00:00 Day 1 of Current Month).
This will includes all the results where date lying in previous month.