# Get data for previous month in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT *
FROM Conference WHERE date_start ---don't know how to proceed---
```

How to check if `date_start` has been in the previous month ? Thanks you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get timestamp of one month ago in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615187/get-timestamp-of-one-month-ago-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Subtract one month from the current month, then "truncate" that to the beginning of that date. As you don't want to include rows from "this" month, you also need to add a condition for that

```
SELECT *
FROM Conference 
WHERE date_start >= date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '1' month)
  and date_start < date_trunc('month', current_date)
```

`date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '1' month)` will return the 1st day of the previous month and `date_trunc('month', current_date)` will return the first day of "this" month.

Comment: The above contains an important typo. It should be `INTERVAL '1 MONTH'` and *not* `INTERVAL '1' MONTH` which returns a 0-length interval.

Comment: @HarryVangberg: no it does not. `interval '1' month` is perfectly valid and does the same as `interval '1 month'`: http://rextester.com/YDDYL97630

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree with Harry. I encountered similar issue as well. '1' month did not work, whereas '1 month' worked.

Comment: @HarryVangberg this syntax in the answer is just fine. Just tested on my DB with no issues

Comment: in Postgresql the syntax must be ```interval '1 month'``` otherwise it doesn't do much, see it yourself: 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html

Comment: @GergelyM: works just fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ce3ba83d9cd833d6f16e06c80db9f04b  or https://i.imgur.com/IQmNs4j.png

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Interesting.  Good to know. Thanks

Comment: how to add timezone info in the above query

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * FROM Conference WHERE date_trunc('month', date_start)=
  date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '1 month')
```

be careful with timezone

```
date_trunc('month', (date_start at time zone 'UTC'))
```

also, you can add an index to make this faster

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_my_date_trunc(period text,
 some_time timestamp with time zone) 
  RETURNS timestamp with time zone
AS
$BODY$
    select date_trunc($1, $2);
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;

CREATE INDEX "IdxConferenceDateStart" ON Conference
 (fn_my_date_trunc('month', (date_start at time zone 'UTC')));
```

and yes, of course you have to use declared function 'fn_my_date_trunc' in your request to use this index automatically(and cast datetime to time zone datetime)