# How to select a range of last month in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I need to write this kind of code

```sql
BETWEEN '2022-02-01' AND '2022-02-28'
```

but to be relative and selecting last month

I tried it this way

```sql
BETWEEN TO_CHAR(current_date - interval '1' month, 'yyyy-mm-01')::date
AND TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(current_date, 'yyyy-mm-01')::date - interval '1' day, 'yyyy-mm-dd')::date
```

but I think there might be better solution to this.

Comment: Hi, does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587910/get-data-for-previous-month-in-postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't convert date values to strings for comparisons. Always use "real" date values.

To get the start of the last month, you can use a combination of `date_trunc()` and subtracting an interval

The start of the last month is the start of "this month" minus one month:

```
date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 month'
```

And the end of the last month is the start of this month minus one day:

```
date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 day'
```

You didn't tell us which data type your column has that you want to compare, but typically it's better to use `>=` and `<` rather than `between` - **especially** if that column is a `timestamp`.

```
where the_column >= date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 month'
  and the_column  < date_trunc('month', current_date)
```