# PostgreSQL - Deleting data that are older than 3 Months command

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, command

PostgreSQL - Deleting data that are older than 3 Months command

Please help me guys with this
i cant find the command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get data for previous month in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587910/get-data-for-previous-month-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
DELETE from table WHERE to_timestamp(last_login) < NOW() - INTERVAL '3 months'
```

Comment: DELETE from table WHERE to_timestamp(last_login) < NOW() - INTERVAL '3 months'    can i replace to_timestamp(last_login) with column-name?

Comment: you can replace last_login with your field and  table with your table, 
to_timestamp is Mysql func